# Adding Code Coverage for catch block in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, code-coverage

Using `2.1.6.RELEASE`

This is my serviceImpl class with repo.save method, in case of db field is duplicate we catch the exception and return in response

```
@Service
public class CoreVoucherServiceImpl implements CoreVoucherService {

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED)
    public VoucherDTO createVoucher(VoucherDTO voucherDTO) {
        ... /* transforming DTO to Entity */
        try {
            voucherRepository.save(voucher);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
                throw new MyException(FIELD_NOT_UNIQUE, "title");
            }
            UB_LOGGER.debug("Error in create voucher", e);
            throw e;
        }
        voucherDTO.setId(voucher.getId());
        return voucherDTO;
    }
}
```

I am not able to add code coverage for the catch block. My Test class is

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CoreVoucherServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private CoreVoucherService coreVoucherService;

    @MockBean
    private VoucherRepository voucherRepository;

    @Test
    // @Test(expected = MyException.class)
    public void createVoucherTest() {
        VoucherDTO dto = prepareCreateVoucher();
        when(voucherRepository.save(any())).thenThrow(Exception.class);
        coreVoucherService.createVoucher(dto);
    }
}
```

with above way I am getting below error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.lang.Exception
```

How do I throw an Exception whose `getCause` is `ConstraintViolationException` so all lines are covered in testing

Comment: have you tried throwing a different type of Exception?

Comment: Yes, but that doesnot cover `MyException` line

Comment: if it's of type ConstraintViolationException, yes, if you throw an Exception, no. Did you read the code you are trying to test? That MyException is only thrown if your try block throws a ConstraintViolationException

Comment: @Stultuske How do I throw an Exception whose `getCause` is `ConstraintViolationException` so all lines are covered in testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test two use cases in your catch block:

When exception cause is `ConstraintViolationException`

```
.thenThrow(new RuntimeException(new ConstraintViolationException("Field not Unique", null, "title")));
```

When exception cause is not `ConstraintViolationException`

```
.thenThrow(new RuntimeException("oops"));
```

for this case `@ExpectedException` would be `RuntimeException`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. the `ConstraintViolationException` is from `org.hibernate.exception`. Hence used `.thenThrow(new RuntimeException(new ConstraintViolationException("Field not Unique", null, "title")))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also test exceptions with @Rule and ExpectedException in Junit.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CoreVoucherServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private CoreVoucherService coreVoucherService;

    @MockBean
    private VoucherRepository voucherRepository;

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exceptionRule = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    // @Test(expected = MyException.class)
    public void createVoucherTest() {
        exceptionRule.expect(Exception.class); // Better if you specify specific Exception class that is going to be thrown.
        VoucherDTO dto = prepareCreateVoucher();
        when(voucherRepository.save(any())).thenThrow(Exception.class);
        coreVoucherService.createVoucher(dto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should throw the `ConstraintViolationException`, because `save` method does not throw any checked exception according to it's method definition [save](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#save-S-)

```
when(voucherRepository.save(any()))
      .thenThrow(.ConstraintViolationException.class);
```

Comment: throwing `RuntimeException` doesnt cover `MyException` line also i have to set `@Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)`

Comment: throw the `ConstraintViolationException` you should be good @KedarJavalkar

Comment: How do I throw an Exception whose `getCause` is `ConstraintViolationException` so all lines are covered in testing

Comment: Have you tried my code? If you try my code your code in the exception block will be covered. @KedarJavalkar

Comment: Yes, i did try., i need an exception whose cause is `ConstraintViolationException`